# Android: Can't find activity in the Manifest, but it IS there?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

And i can't figure out why! I checked logcat and i saw that the reason it crashed was because it isn't finding the Activity in the manifest file for some unknown reason.

I've looked at similar threads but none of the answers seem to work for me.

Here's the code where i start the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent ntnt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(ntnt);

    }
}
```

And the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="se.jbhalmstad.ndroid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see i declared the SettingsActivity that i'm trying to start, at the bottom of the Manifest, inside of the  tag.

I might be blind, but i can't find anything wrong. Can you?

Let me know if you need more source, but the SettingsActivity should be irrelevant because it doesn't get that var when i run the program.

---

### Source code

If you want to take a closer look, here's the entire source code.

http://www.speedyshare.com/files/30343046/project.zip

Comment: There is inflation error in your `settings.xml` which cause problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `SettingsActivity`
when you are using `PreferenceActivity` you use

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);
```

to set contents.
but you are using

```
setContentView(R.layout.settings);
```

Answer (score 3):

Could be package name mismatch. What Java package is the activity class in? Must match the one in the manifest, i. e. `se.jbhalmstad.ndroid`. Or provide full class name in the `android:name` attribute.

EDIT: I have a working example, and the `<activity>` element for my Preferences activity looks slightly different:

```
<activity android:name="Prefs"/>
```

No dot before `Prefs`.

Also, check if the SettingsActivity class is public. You never showed it to us.

Comment: Nope, they match. :/ Any other suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out! The thread i'm trying to start (SettingsActivity) extends PreferenceActivity, and that seems to cause it to not work. How do i declare the activity in the Manifest if it's a PreferenceActivity? I tried writing <PreferenceActivity> instead of <activity> with no result (tried with both lowercase and capitalized)

Comment: It's still just an activity, so you shouldn't have to change it.

Comment: First, SettingsActivity had better be a PreferenceActivity and not a Thread.  Second, PreferenceActivities are still Activities, and are declared in the Manifest exactly as a normal Activity would be.  I don't think this is your problem.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help either. And yes, SettingsActivity is a PreferenceActivity and not a thread. You can take a look at the entire source if you want to, i added it to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont need to add the name of the package to your acitivity name ,  you can just  add your activity SettingActivity like this :

```
<activity android:name="SettingsActivity" />
```

because your activity is in the same package that is declared on the manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="se.jbhalmstad.ndroid"...
```

let me know if  it helps

Comment: add the Dot (.) to your activity  !!

Comment: That's how it was from the beginning, still doesn't work :( This is insane, i just don't get it. And nobody else seems to find it either, really weird!

Comment: i'm now at work , and i'm working on a MACBOOK whithout eclipse and Android sdk  , i will see your project at night to figure out what is the problem , it should works , and one advice , try to Clean an rebuild your project if you change on xml files ( manifest , layouts ...etc ) , good luck ,

Comment: or try to create a new simple Activity with a simple textView to display at the same package of the other activities,  and add it to your manifest, and see if it will work or not

Comment: Adil figured it out. The problem was i was using setContentView() to set the view in SettingsActivity, but since it's a PreferenceActivity you must use addPreferencesFromResource() instead. Thanks though! :)

Comment: glad to hear it , happy for you , and thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Manifest intent on the right activity and not just the basic Java / Kotlin class file
`New -> Activity -> Empty Activity` instead of `New -> Class/file`
or
Use `setContentView(R.layout.yours_activity_class_here);` OnCreate